# How do I get vim to read syntax files from `/usr/share/vim/addons/syntax`?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, linux-ubuntu, path

According to the [Debian documentation about vim](https://vim-team.pages.debian.net/vim/x126.html), a Debian package (Ubuntu, really, in my case) is expected to place `<name>.vim` files under:

```
/usr/share/vim/addons/...
```

Syntax files go under a sub-directory named syntax:

```
/usr/share/vim/addons/syntax/my-syntax.vim
```

However, it does not look like `vim` recognized that directory.

In my `.vimrc` file I have something like so:

```
syntax on
if !exists("my_autocommands_loaded")
  let my_autocommands_loaded=1
  au BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.cpp  setf my-syntax
endif
```

Just in case, I also tried `:setf my-syntax` manually and I lose the syntax (which I know is what happens when a file is not found). Looking around, it sounds like the only path to a system syntax folder would be the path to `/usr/share/vim/vim<version>/syntax/...`.

I also replaced the `setf ...` with `so /usr/shared/vim/addons/syntax/my-syntax.vim` and that works perfectly.

Is it not possible to use that `addons` directory? Do I need to add it in a variable? Is it necessary to have a corresponding plugin which properly activates the `addons` syntax?

Comment: Yeah, actually, I think the better bet is to add the root to `'runtimepath'` since the structure you mention above doesn't have the required `{packdir}/start`. Take a look at the page that you're taken to when you hit the `Prev` link.

Comment: @BLayer Ah, interesting, there is a path for addons under `/varr/lib/...`: `runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vim80/pack/dist/opt/matchit,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after`

Comment: Hmm, seems like an awful lot of system level directories are in there. Anyways, if you add `/usr/share/vim/addons` everything should be picked up.

Comment: @BLayer I was testing... That helped in the sense that it found the plugins, but it still fails finding the syntax files. (I checked with `:scriptnames`). At this point I don't have plugins, only syntax files. The rest is in my `.vimrc` file.

Comment: Ah, okay. Someone else will have to help you with that...I gotta run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Addons" is just another directory that could be added to `:h 'runtimepath'` by `:h system-vimrc`. It is intended for package manager (`sudo apt install vim-foobar` goes here). For this reason, you're not adviced to do anything with it.

Except for this, your question is unclear to me, as the code is simply broken. If what you're trying is to extend C++ syntax then make use of `:h after-directory`, e.g. `~/.vim/after/syntax/cpp.vim`, as usual.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a Debian package which, when installed, gives all the users access to those files. This is my own personal package. A Debian package is not expected to install files under a `~/...` directory. So **I am** doing a `sudo apt install my-package`.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Before trying to package something you should create and debug "a regular version" that works. Just manually put all files under `~/.vim` and check if it's doing something at least for the current user.

Comment: Matt, I feel that the question still stands: In a default (?) Debian installation, `/usr/share/vim/addons/` is not in `runtimepath`, despite the fact that lots of packages install syntax files there. As you say, "It is intended for package manager". So what is the proper way to "activate" this path?

Comment: The answer, which I forgot, is that things in `addons/` are managed by [`vim-addon-manager`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/vim-addon-manager/vam.1.en.html).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Debian Vim build only embeds `/var/lib/vim/addons` into default rtp, but not `/usr/share/vim/addons`. So it has to be `:set` somewhere inside vimrc's. Probably, assisted by vam.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That looks like my answer. It would get installed under `/usr/share/vim/addons` and the user has to install the script with `vim-addons install <name>`. I can see that the `vim-scripts` package offers such so I can follow that package's functionality now that I understand how it work (i.e. that you have to run `vim-addons ...`).